# Keep empty bins/buckets in final GroupBy even if there is no data to populate them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have successfully bucketted my data:

```
bins = [-np.inf,0,10000,20000,40000,60000,80000,100000,np.inf]  # include infinity value as the endpoint to the bins
labels = ['0','10K', '20K','40K','60K', '80K','100K','> 100K']
df_Done = df[
                (df['state'].str.contains('Done'))
                ][['Year_Month','rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv']].copy()
display(df_Done.head(5))

Year_Month  rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv
2018-05     259,774
2018-05     259,774
2018-05     363,684
2018-05     3,896,610
2018-05     666,340

df_Done.info()
Year_Month           700 non-null object
rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv    700 non-null float64
Bucket               700 non-null category

df_Done['Bucket'] = pd.cut(df_Done['rfq_qty_CAD_Equiv'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
display(df_Done.groupby(['Year_Month','Bucket'], as_index=False)['Bucket'].size())
```

From month to month some buckets may have no trades, in which case I would like the bucket line to appear with a zero. Example in the result below, there is no 10K bucket for 2017-11 (want to see 10K and a 0). Is there a way to insert the bins/buckets even if there are no trades there to populate these buckets?

Also is there a way to ouput the result not in text format but in grid format?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by new `MultiIndex` created by [`from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with categories by [`cat.categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.categories.html):

```
df = df_Done.groupby(['Year_Month','Bucket'], as_index=False)['Bucket'].size()

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_Done['Year_Month'].unique(),
                                  df_Done['Bucket'].cat.categories])
df = df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
print (df)
2018-05  0         0
         10K       0
         20K       0
         40K       0
         60K       0
         80K       0
         100K      0
         > 100K    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Getting are error on mux = ....
DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: Bucket

Comment: Interesting, for me it working. I try change solution, please check it.